# Infopath form to show available days from Sharepoint list

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-list, data-connections

I have an InfoPath form with a calendar picker with a connection to a SharePoint list which displays days. is it possible to show the days from the SharePoint list on the InfoPath calendar?
e.g Sharepoint list days Wednesday, Friday. InfoPath calendar picker shows every Wednesday and Friday as available?